# Error when building the jar file in spring boot

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.1.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) on project od-api: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.1.RELEASE:repackage failed: 
Unable to load the mojo 'repackage' in the plugin 
'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.1.RELEASE' 
due to an API incompatibility: 
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException:
 JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/springframework/boot/maven/RepackageMojo, offset=6
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.1.RELEASE
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Dumping an error message and expecting a solutions isn't a good way of asking a question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question. With that knowledge please update your question. Hint use proper formatting and you might want to add your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Supplemental informations like Maven version? JDK version etc. How have you called Maven would support other to identify the issue...